# MATLAB: Generating function depending on user input

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab and am having trouble with the following.

I am using an external function, "allcomb" that allows me to create a combination of the elements from arrays.

For example, i have an array C [1 2 3 4] and an integer X of any value between 1 to 20. The results I want is simply,

```
if X is 1, my function will be allcomb(C)
if X is 2, my function will be allcomb(C,C)
if X is 6, my function will be allcomb(C,C,C,C,C,C)
```

... so on.

instead of creating a if condition, what would be a better way of doing it?

Thanks for you interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The long way using strings is not necessary, use the [**comma separated list**](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) operator **`:`** instead:

```
C = [1 2 3 4];
X = 2

in = repmat( {C}, X, 1 )

allcomb( in{:} )
```

as example `allcomb` just displays the input:

```
function allcomb( varargin )
celldisp(varargin)
end
```

returns for `X = 2`:

```
varargin{1} =

     1     2     3     4

varargin{2} =

     1     2     3     4
```

and for `X = 4`:

```
varargin{1} =

     1     2     3     4

varargin{2} =

     1     2     3     4

varargin{3} =

     1     2     3     4

varargin{4} =

     1     2     3     4
```

Comment: This is promising. Learnt something new. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the output of 'allcomb' goes to a certain variable 'out' (i.e. "out = allcomb(C,C,C);" for X=3), I think this might work -

```
out_string = 'out = '; %// Edit this to change output behaviour.
                       %// For example set it to empty string '' if no output
                       %// is needed.

str1 = repmat('C,',[1 X]);
str1(end) = [];

evalc_string = [out_string 'allcomb(' str1 ');'];
evalc(evalc_string);
```

This was a dirty hack really. If you have editable rights to 'allcomb', it would be wiser to use [variable-length input method](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) for MATLAB functions.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy with a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html):

```
C = [1 2 3 4];
n = 6; %// number of arguments (all equal to C) to pass to allcomb

CC = mat2cell(repmat(C,n,1),ones(1,n),numel(C)); %// nx1 cell array containing C
allcomb(CC{:}) %// call allcomb. Note CC{:} is just C,C,...C (n times)
```